# How does Arduino decide when to go into flashing mode and normal mode?

Tags: esp8266

Just this general question.As the titles says.

How does Arduino decide when to go into flashing mode and normal mode?

Is it by connecting certain pins to ground,so it's a hardware check or does it have to do with the code?

Other similar arduino like products such as the esp8266 work the same way as long as they use the same chip?

Comment: esp8266 chip is unrelated to anything arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It first runs the bootloader. If there is no data coming into the serial connection within a certain amount, i.e. it's not being programmed, it will exit the bootloader and start the actual sketch.

In the UNO you will notice a 3 second delay between providing power, and your sketch starting.